# Using Google Authentication on iPhones on Aruba wireless

Tags: google-cloud-platform, authentication, wifi, ios, aruba

We have set up Google Authentication for our Aruba WiFi network. We are using Central (v 8 and 10 - both have the issue) and AP-515s and AP-535s. The solution works as expected on every platform except iPhones. We use it on Windows (10 and 11), MacOS (10.12.6 - 13.4.1(c)), iPads (14-16.5.1(c)), Android phones (version unknown - not mine), and even Chromebooks (98-114), with no issues.

However, when we try to authenticate with Google on iPhones, we get an error: `Access blocked: Authorization Error / Error 403:disallowed_useragent`

If we cancel the dialog and tell it to run without Internet, then go into Safari or Chrome and surf to any unencrypted website (encrypted sites give a certificate error) we are then allowed to authenticate with Google and everything starts working as expected.

I have tickets open with Aruba and Google Workspace Support. The latter punted and said try Google Cloud Support. However, I work for a school district, and we don't have paid support for Google beyond Workspace. Aruba is working with Google, but I was wondering: could we really be the only people trying to use an Aruba wireless network with Google authentication, that's having trouble on the iPhones?

Verified correct function on several other platforms, and verified problem on several different iPhones, running iOS versions 15 and 16, with and without Chrome installed and with and without Chrome set to the default browser.

Thanks in advance for any insights.